# Intent for Google Play Store "Manage apps & device" (My apps / Updates) does not work anymore

Tags: android-intent, google-play

Previously, Google Play - My apps & games (Updates)

```
Action  : com.google.android.finsky.VIEW_MY_DOWNLOADS
Package : com.android.vending
Class   : com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity
Target  : Activity
```

Now new Google Play Store updated to a new UI and those intent didn't work anymore.

I would like to goes to this page directly:
[image: My apps & device page in Google Play Store]

Is there any new replacement intent?

Comment: This *does* work - at least on Android 13. Came here from this other thread and answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/245035/accessing-available-app-updates-in-play-store-app-through-a-shortcut#answer-245144